# Windows 8's Fax and Scan doesn't recognize my HP 7310

Tags: windows-8, scanner, hp-officejet, multi-function-printer

When I had Windows 7 I successfully scanned documents with my 7310 AIO operating as scanner.

Now that I upgraded to Windows 8 Windows Fax and Scan doesn't detect any attached scanner.

I tried to uninstall the drivers and reinstall them (after downloading a version that claims to be compatible with Win 8) but the installation fails.

How can I fix this? Error message is "No scanner detected..."

If I use Control Panel's scanner and digital cameras function I am required to (manually) install a scanner driver which I don't currently have. Or at least the devices list doesn't show any HP device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you gone to the HP website to look for Windows 8 drivers for your All in One? [This page](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&product=391182) should be the correct one for the model that you listed. Just choose which version of Windows 8 that you have to get the correct driver.

I found the download page by searching for "HP 7310" in the [Windows Compatibility Center](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/win8/CompatCenter/ProductDetailsViewer?Name=HP%20OfficeJet%207310%20All-in-One%20Printer&vendor=HP&Locale=1033&ModelOrVersion=Q5562B&BreadCrumbPath=hp%207310&Type=Hardware&tempOsid=win8) which shows that the printer/scanner IS compatible with Windows 8 and gives the link to the driver download page.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Printing works fine anyway. The first page you linked corresponds to the download I tried and failed its installation (the installer simply closed). I'll try again.

Comment: That should be the correct file, but it's large (413MB). The data shows that this file is for all versions of Windows 8. It's possible that you must start the install using the 'run as administrator' option, if you didn't already.